# How can I add server side image rendering support

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have recently become interested in the subject of server side rendering and have written an application through articles and tutorials that works, but does not show the images that are in the application. I would like my server rendering the App component to render it together with the image in it, but I can't find a way to do it.

**Server.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import App from '../src/App'

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('something went wrong ', err)
            return res.status(500).send('better luck next time')
        }

        return res.send(
            data.replace(
                '<div id="root"></div>',
                `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
            )
        )
    })
}) 

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App running on ${PORT}`)
})
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import p1 from './images/p1.jpg'

const App = (context) => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrament = () => {
    setCount(count+1)
  }

  const handleDecrament = () => {
    setCount(count -1)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleIncrament}>Incrament</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrament}>Decrament</button>
      <img src={p1} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Doesn't this line of code provide access to all the files in the build folder along with the media files?
`app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))`

I also saw in one of the topics a method to work around this problem by eliminating the imports for images and replacing them with the absolute path to the file. However, before reaching for this solution, I would like to ask if there is any other way? Without removing the import syntax?

Comment: All the image file should be available in server at a public location. And to make them available to clients we should use `router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "..", "public")));`

Comment: What if my backend and frontend share the same public folder? I tried to do as you wrote, but it is still the same. On the client side I couldn't import from the public folder because it is outside of src, so in this case the image file should be in src for the client side application and in public for the server? I am new to this and do not fully understand everything about ssr. Thank you for your comment